# Matching multiple keywords using contains() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, contains

Currently matching a specific keyword using contains(). How can i expand this to include multiple keywords?
have tried using the || (or) operator, but no joy.

```
<!-- Product names include Apple iPad, Acer Iconia, Lenovo Thinkpad -->

<h1 id="pbtitle">Apple iPad 3</h1>


<div class="install_option" style="display:none;">              
        <div style="box-sizing:border-box; float:left;">
            <a href="https://www.exmaple.com/acc" target="_blank">
                <h3 style="font-weight:bold;">Would you like to view accessories?</h3>
            </a>    
        </div>

</div>


$(".install_option").each(function() {
    if($("h1#pbtitle:contains:contains('Acer' || 'Lenovo' || Apple )").length>0){
      $('.install_option').css('display','block');
    }
});
```

Comment: [Jquery "contains" multiple values](//stackoverflow.com/q/23248809), [jQuery :contains selector to search for multiple strings](//stackoverflow.com/q/2416803)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaScript function [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
Working example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mqekp3qh/)

```
var options = ['Acer','Lenovo','Apple']; // options that you want to look for
var text = $("#pbtitle").text();         // string where you want to look in

options.forEach( function( element ) {
    if ( text.indexOf( element ) != -1 ) {    // if its NOT -1 (-1 = not found)
      alert( 'found' );                       // then we found it .. do your magic
    }
})
```

Comment: This has done the job, anyway of EXCLUDING a keyword such as Generic?

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

`if($("h1#pbtitle:contains('Acer'),h1#pbtitle:contains('Lenovo'),h1#pbtitle:contains('Apple')").length>0)`

Answer (score 0):

Risking being a bit out of the question scope, I guess the product list is dynamic in same kind.
In that case it will be better to add a property to the product tag like:

```
<h1 id="pbtitle" has_install_option="true">Apple iPad 3</h1>

var condition = $('h1#pbtitle').attr('has_install_option') == 'true';
```

and checking that condition in your loop.
[think of the day you will have an Apple product with install_option or an Appleseed product...]

p.s in this example it's better to place the condition out side of the loop as the condition is static in relation to the looped elements